# matlab compiled in docker

Tags: matlab, docker, compiler-errors

I am experimenting with compiling MATLAB functions and running them in docker containers. When I run the .sh file on my computer it works alright but when I put that file in a container and run it from there it gives me "Unterminated quoted string" error. What's wrong with my sh file ? I used a Mac to compile my function but I am using linux in containers. Do you think that is the issue ?

```
#!/bin/sh
# script for execution of deployed applications
#
# Sets up the MATLAB Runtime environment for the current $ARCH and executes 
# the specified command.
#
exe_name=$0
exe_dir=`dirname "$0"`
echo "------------------------------------------"
if [ "x$1" = "x" ]; then
  echo Usage:
  echo    $0 \<deployedMCRroot\> args
else
  echo Setting up environment variables
  MCRROOT="$1"
  echo ---
  DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:${MCRROOT}/runtime/maci64 ;
  DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${MCRROOT}/bin/maci64 ;
  DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${MCRROOT}/sys/os/maci64;
  export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH;
  echo DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is ${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH};
  shift 1
  args=
  while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
      token=$1
      args="${args} \"${token}\"" 
      shift
  done
  eval "\"${exe_dir}/helloworld_times.app/Contents/MacOS/helloworld_times\"" $args
fi
exit
```

Comment: Including your whole Dockerfile would be helpful, but yes, there are a couple of things in that shell script that are very MacOS-specific and do not look like I'd expect on Linux.

Comment: I don't think you can create a Linux executable on MacOS. You might have to run the compiler on Linux. The MATLAB Compiler creates a binary executable, and these are not portable across platforms. I haven't found a switch where you can specify the target platform.